# Terraform setproduct where values from both lists are only known after apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Aim: Create a Terraform module that creates AWS SSO users, groups and group memberships. The groups and users are created by a for loop. Once all are created, each user created should be assigned to each group created.

It appears that setproduct is probably the best solution for this, however the group membership step is failing as it is not getting the correct values (User ID and group ID are required for each membership)

This is my variables.tf file for the module, the users and groups are created correctly:

```
data "aws_ssoadmin_instances" "ssoadmin_instances" {}
output "arn" {
  value = tolist(data.aws_ssoadmin_instances.ssoadmin_instances.arns)[0]
}
output "identity_store_id" {
  value = tolist(data.aws_ssoadmin_instances.ssoadmin_instances.identity_store_ids)[0]
}

locals {
  users = {
    "user1" = {
      username = "test.user"
      email    = "test.user@example.com"
      first_name = "Test"
      surname = "User"
    },
    "user2" = {
      username = "test.user2"
      email    = "test.user2@example.com"
      first_name = "Test"
      surname = "User2"
    }
  }
  groups = {
    "group1" = {
      group_name = "test-management-admin"
      description    = "Management account administrators"
    },
    "group2" = {
      group_name = "test-management-readonly"
      description    = "Management account readonly"
    }
  }
}
```

This is main.tf:

```
# Groups

resource "aws_identitystore_group" "groups" {
  for_each = local.groups

  description       = each.value.description
  display_name      = each.value.group_name
  identity_store_id = tolist(data.aws_ssoadmin_instances.ssoadmin_instances.identity_store_ids)[0]
}

# Users

resource "aws_identitystore_user" "users" {
  for_each = local.users

  display_name = join(" ", [each.value.first_name, each.value.surname])
  emails {
    value = each.value.email
  }
  identity_store_id = tolist(data.aws_ssoadmin_instances.ssoadmin_instances.identity_store_ids)[0]
  name {
    given_name  = each.value.first_name
    family_name = each.value.surname
  }
  user_name = each.value.username
}

# Group Membership

locals {
  user_ids = [
    for user_key, user in aws_identitystore_user.users : {
      key     = user_key
      user_id = user.user_id
    }
  ]
  group_ids = [
    for group_key, group in aws_identitystore_group.groups : {
      key      = group_key
      group_id = group.group_id
    }
  ]
  memberships = [
    for pair in setproduct(local.user_ids, local.group_ids) : {
      user_key  = pair[0].key
      group_key = pair[1].key
    }
  ]
}

resource "aws_identitystore_group_membership" "memberships" {
  for_each = {
    for membership in local.memberships : "${membership.user_key}.${membership.group_key}" => membership
  }

  identity_store_id = tolist(data.aws_ssoadmin_instances.ssoadmin_instances.identity_store_ids)[0]
  group_id          = each.value.group_key
  member_id         = each.value.user_key

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

When I run a plan, Terraform does detect that there are two groups and two users and thus a total of four memberships are required. However it fails because it is not getting the correct user_id and group_id values (it appears to be using a placeholder value? NB these users and groups do exist so the values should be available), what am I doing wrong?

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.sso-base-identity.aws_identitystore_group_membership.memberships["user1.group1"] will be created
  + resource "aws_identitystore_group_membership" "memberships" {
      + group_id          = "group1"
      + id                = (known after apply)
      + identity_store_id = "d-93670a4657"
      + member_id         = "user1"
      + membership_id     = (known after apply)
    }

  # module.sso-base-identity.aws_identitystore_group_membership.memberships["user1.group2"] will be created
  + resource "aws_identitystore_group_membership" "memberships" {
      + group_id          = "group2"
      + id                = (known after apply)
      + identity_store_id = "d-93670a4657"
      + member_id         = "user1"
      + membership_id     = (known after apply)
    }

  # module.sso-base-identity.aws_identitystore_group_membership.memberships["user2.group1"] will be created
  + resource "aws_identitystore_group_membership" "memberships" {
      + group_id          = "group1"
      + id                = (known after apply)
      + identity_store_id = "d-93670a4657"
      + member_id         = "user2"
      + membership_id     = (known after apply)
    }

  # module.sso-base-identity.aws_identitystore_group_membership.memberships["user2.group2"] will be created
  + resource "aws_identitystore_group_membership" "memberships" {
      + group_id          = "group2"
      + id                = (known after apply)
      + identity_store_id = "d-93670a4657"
      + member_id         = "user2"
      + membership_id     = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 4 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Comment: Where are the `aws_ssoadmin_instances` comming from? Also, the reason you are getting the same `identity_store_id` is probably because you are fetching only the first element.

Comment: `aws_ssoadmin_instances` is from the variables file. The `identity_store_id` is correct, there is only one value for it. The issue is that the group_id and member_id in `aws_identitystore_group_membership` should not be user1, user2 etc.

Comment: And you would expect it to be what?

Comment: The user and group IDs look like this `93670a2513-be2d84ca-3ffe-4360-b7d9-912975bb399e`. They are only known after creation, which is a limitation I can live with.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working after using outputs to view the values for the locals. Under `local.memberships` I was getting the value of the key instead of the relevant ID. So I replaced `pair[0].key` and `pair[1].key` as below:

```
  memberships = [
    for pair in setproduct(local.user_ids, local.group_ids) : {
      user_key  = pair[0].user_id
      group_key = pair[1].group_id
    }
  ]
```